# SQL Statement: Getting results based on 2 values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a pretty complex SQL statement and want to add a WHERE clause that only selects results WHERE the `hidden` column IS NOT '1', however it needs to relate to a specific user.

i.e If in table 1 `hidden` is 1 and `userid` is 1 I don't want to get this results. However as there is no record for user 2 in that table I want them to see it.

This is what I have managed to get working so far:

```
$where .= " AND uh.hidden IS NULL ";
```

However if I login as User 2 then I see the same results as user 1.

How do I make it so results are shown based on the user too?

SQL query:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB', 'root', 'root');
$select = 'SELECT tl.id,
                  tl.name,
                  tl.locale,
                  ROUND(AVG(pr.rating),0) AS rating ';

$from  = ' FROM theList AS tl ';
$join  = ' LEFT JOIN post_rating AS pr ON tl.id = pr.postid ';
$join2 = ' LEFT JOIN user_hidden_list AS uh ON uh.est_id = tl.id ';
$opts  = isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : [''];

$where = ' WHERE 1 = 1 ';
if (in_array("pub", $opts)) {
    $where .= " AND pub = 1";
}
if (in_array("bar", $opts)) {
    $where .= " AND bar = 1";
}
$where = ' WHERE uh.hidden IS NULL ';

$group = ' GROUP BY tl.id, tl.name ';

$sql = $select . $from . $join . $join2 . $where . $group;

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
```

Comment: a table definition would be useful to see

Comment: Can you show your table and the expected result for each case ?

Comment: Also the `FROM`, `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses of your query....

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I have added my full query!

Comment: you always overwrite `$where`. Maybe you want an `if - elseif - else`?

Comment: This is a simplified version, I'm using some checkboxes!

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto Do you have any suggestions

Comment: What is the resulting query? Did try to log it out, and to run it manually?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto I'll try that and let you know! Thanks for your help!